# tracking dropbox share link download count in rails and preserve byte-range request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i would like to track the download count of the dropbox share link in rails. What I am doing is the follows: have a method and increase the counter and then redirect to dropbox share link.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.any(:mp3, :mp4, :m4a, :mov, :m4v) {
     @audio.download_count = @audio.download_count + 1
     @audio.save 
     redirect_to "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9296785/sample.mp3"        
  }
end
```

The counter is working fine, and the redirection works fine too. But it lose the byte-range request property.

```
curl --silent --range 20-40 http://localhost:3000/audio/1.mp3
```

the result is not 21 bytes. Suppose if the link is byte-range request, then request from 20 to 40 will result to 21 bytes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean "the result is not 21 bytes"?  I have not integrated with Dropbox but I don't see where you are downloading anything.  You might update your post with some information about how you are integrating (SDK/gem/etc).